# How do I NOT show a widget on 3D touch in ios 10

Tags: ios, swift3, widget

I have a widget and 3D touch action. How do I disable widget being shown on 3D touch. I just want to show the actions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer myself. In case anyone is wondering I went to info.plist and added a key Home Screen Widget and set it to none. I don't know if this is a proper way to do it but it works for me.